# .NET Core 8 docker build issue with shared library

Tags: docker, .net-core, .net-8.0

I have a .NET Core 8.0 app with the following folder structure:

```
... some other folders and files ...

Services
   --- AuthService
      AuthService.csproj
      Dockerfile
   --- CommonLib
      CommonLib.csproj

... some other folders and files ...
```

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 7501

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:7501

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Services/AuthService/AuthService.csproj", "AuthService/"]
COPY ["Services/CommonLib/CommonLib.csproj", "CommonLib/"]
RUN dotnet restore "AuthService\AuthService.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/AuthService"
RUN dotnet build "AuthService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "AuthService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AuthService.dll"]
```

From the root of the project, when I run this:

```
docker build . -f Services/AuthService/Dockerfile
```

I get the following error:

```
 => ERROR [build 10/10] RUN dotnet build "AuthService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build                                                                                                                                                                   5.3s 
------
 > [build 10/10] RUN dotnet build "AuthService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build:
#18 0.662 MSBuild version 17.9.4+90725d08d for .NET
#18 1.526   Determining projects to restore...
#18 2.152   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
#18 4.428   CommonLib -> /app/build/CommonLib.dll
#18 5.192 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/AuthService/AuthService.csproj]
#18 5.213
#18 5.214 Build FAILED.
#18 5.214
#18 5.214 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/AuthService/AuthService.csproj]
#18 5.214     0 Warning(s)
#18 5.214     1 Error(s)
#18 5.215
#18 5.215 Time Elapsed 00:00:04.39
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet build "AuthService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build]: exit code: 1
```

In the `AuthService` project, I am referencing the `CommonLib` like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CommonLib\CommonLib.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I have tried many different configurations of paths, but nothing seems to work. I am at a complete loss.

What am I missing?

EDIT:  I should have probably mentioned that the `AuthService` builds without any issues if I build it directly using `dotnet build`. So does the `CommonLib`.

EDIT2: Here is the AuthService.csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="8.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CommonLib\CommonLib.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: @IanKemp see my edit.  And yes, I have been staring it for 2 days.  Hence my question.

Comment: Does it build locally without docker? Can you post a [mre] somewhere (like github)?

Comment: Could you share the whole content of the `AuthService.csproj`?

Comment: @GuruStron, yes, if I build it outside docker, it builds without any issues.

Comment: @RafalKozlowski, see my Edit2 above

Comment: My guess is that you are coping files to wrong folders. If I have read docker file correctly - you will have `AuthService.csproj` in `/src/AuthService/` while everything else will be in `/src/Services/...`

Comment: @GuruStron I have a similar suspicion.  Something is up with the folders and paths.  Docker is not my forte, so I might have done it wrong.  This docker file worked fine before I added the CommonLib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are coping files to wrong folders. If I have read docker file correctly - you will have `AuthService.csproj` in `/src/AuthService/` while everything else will be in `/src/Services/...`.

Try calling `WORKDIR "/src/Services/AuthService"` before build:

```
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Services/AuthService"
RUN dotnet build "AuthService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
```

And updating the copy/restore commands:

```
COPY ["Services/AuthService/AuthService.csproj", "Services/AuthService/"]
COPY ["Services/CommonLib/CommonLib.csproj", "Services/CommonLib/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Services\AuthService\AuthService.csproj"
```